# React Object.keys

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день, пытаюсь получить массив через Api с помощью Object.key(obj).map, но мне выдает только его номер. Может кто помочь, что не правильно делаю?

Мой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:
Проверяю массив:

```
var nameObj = item.categories;

Object.keys(nameObj).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + ': ' + nameObj[name]);
});
```

Пытаюсь вывести:

```
    let item = this.props.item;
    return (
                        <div className="back-info">
                            <p className='grey-text text-lighten-1'>Color:</p>
                            {Object.keys(item.colors).map((id, name) => {
                                return (
                                    <a key={id} className='grey-text text-darken-4'>{name}</a>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
)
```

Далее выводит вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вместо названия цифру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту `item.colors` это массив, массивы выводятся так

```
{item.colors.map((color) => {
  return (
    <a key={color.id} className='grey-text text-darken-4'>{color.name}</a>
  )
})}
```

Или так, если ваш препроцессор JSX поддерживает такой синтаксис

```
{item.colors.map(({id, name}) => {
  return (
    <a key={id} className='grey-text text-darken-4'>{name}</a>
  )
})}
```